# How did Severus know where the Cloak of Invisibility was?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*, Severus goes into the Shrieking Shack with Harry's Invisibility Cloak on him.

> Harry's fists clenched as they watched Snape skid to a halt next to the tree, looking around. He grabbed the cloak and held it up.

**How did he know where it was?**

Comment: It is a cloak of invisibility, not an invisible cloak.

Comment: Are you asking where Snape found it?

Answer (score -1):

The cloak is not invisible from both side. [image]

Got it from http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Cloak_of_Invisibility